# Selenium MoveToElement does not work but test cases are passing

Tags: java, selenium, debugging, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

In Below scenario, I am trying to select Option4-1 from the main menu. Have used moveToElement(), click(). use case shows as pass when i execute my script but i don't see the slide in window appearing which is expected behavior after clicking "option4-1".

[image: Image shows option menus]

**Code:**

```
public class CreateppPage extends PageFactory {

private WebDriver driver;
private WebDriverWait wait;
private Actions act;
/**
      Selectors section
 */

@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='Main Button']")
private WebElement AddMenu;
@FindBy(xpath="//li[@class='item-submenu']//span[contains(text(),'Option4')]")
private WebElement subMenu;
@FindBy(xpath="//span[contains(text(),'Option4-1')]")
private WebElement subsubMenu;

/*****************Methods section***********************/

public CreateppPage(WebDriver driver, long wait) {
    
    this.driver = driver;
    this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,wait);
    initElements(driver, this);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

public void createMpp() {
    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(AddMenu));
    act = new Actions(driver);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        act.moveToElement(AddMenu).click().build();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        act.moveToElement(subMenu).click().moveToElement(subsubMenu).click().build();
        Thread.sleep(10000);    
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `.perform()`
It should be

```
act.moveToElement(AddMenu).click().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(1000);
act.moveToElement(subMenu).moveToElement(subsubMenu).click().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

I also suggest to reduce or even remove the hardcoded delays.
Explicit waits should be used instead.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(AddMenu));
act.moveToElement(AddMenu).click().build().perform();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(subsubMenu));
act.moveToElement(subMenu).moveToElement(subsubMenu).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: can you add the second answer as first approach. Coincidently was able to solve myself with same approach. And  i did add click(webelement) just to double sure on the click (not sure required though). It looked something like : act.moveToElement(AddMenu).click(AddMenu).build.perform()

Comment: There is only 1 approach in my answer. The first code is a basic idea while the second is the same idea but with additional details,  removing the hardcoded sleeps and using explicit wait instead. If you want, I can remove the first code and leave the second only since this is how it actually should be.

Comment: @vinsr04 so, you want me to leave the final code only?

Comment: Yes.. That makes sense. Even I had added sleep just for debugging purpose.

Comment: Hi Again, I facing problem regarding same menu.  Driver is clicking main button when page still loading, so sub menu's are not appearing.  Any idea on how to solve this? (wait till elementToBeClickable did not solve).

Comment: What about waiting for visibility instead of clickability?

Comment: tried both. Basically element is available for driver to click, so it clicks but submenu does not load as page is still loading.

Comment: I can't debug this.. So, it's not an elegant way, but you can put a simple sleep of several seconds there.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do like this  :

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(AddMenu).click().moveToElement(subsubMenu).click().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
moveToElement() Moves the mouse to the middle of the element.

Build(): creates the chain of the actions that need to be 
performed

perform(): perform those chain of actions which is build by using 
Action build method.

Internally the perform() called the build() method so if we call 
the build().perform() explicitly so we are calling .build() twice

So it seems like you miss the .perform()

act.moveToElement(subMenu).click()
.moveToElement(subsubMenu).click().build().perform();

OR

act.moveToElement(subMenu).click()
.moveToElement(subsubMenu).click().perform();
```

> .perform() : A convenience method for performing the actions without calling build() first.